# jQuery - how to combine many click operations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to react to click events of dynamically created elements. Is there an elegant way to combine the functions, that I only have to listen once to a click in the body? Some of the elements have several classes.

HTML

```
<div class="dropDown blueBG"></div>
```

JS

```
      $("body").on('click', '.dropDown', function(e){
          .......
      });

      $("body").on('click', '.aButton', function(e){
          .......
      });

      $("body").on('click', '.aForm', function(e){
          .......
      });
```

Comment: Do you wan to do the same thing for all of the elements, or different things for different elements?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I need different functionalities for each element. So you would keep it as it is?

Comment: @ user: Yes, if the handlers do different things, there's no reason to combine them. If they have *parts* in common, factor those into separate small functions they each call (so you're not duplicating code).

Answer (score 3):

Try to use the [`multiple selector`](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/),

*same function for all the elements:*

```
$("body").on('click', '.dropDown,.aButton,.aForm', function(e){ 
});
```

*different functionality for different elements:*

```
$("body").on('click', '.dropDown,.aButton,.aForm', function(e){ 

    if      ($(this).is('.dropDown')) { }
    else if ($(this).is('.aButton'))  { }
    else                              { }

});
```

Comment: There is, of course, fundamentally no good reason to do the second thing. Separate handlers is the correct approach.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i just used the second one in some of my projects in order to improve the code elegance and minimize the effect of code repetition. Am i going in a right way or wat..?

Comment: @ Raj: Impossible to say without seeing the specifics, but I probably would lean toward separate handlers. If they have things in common, factor that out into smaller functions they call. What you're doing (logically, not literally) in that second code block is asking jQuery to combine those classes just so you can separate them out again. So for one thing, you end up duplicating the selectors.

Answer (score 3):

Combine them in the selector using a comma to separate them:

```
$("body").on('click', '.dropDown, .aButton, .aForm', function(e){

});
```

If you want to find out what was clicked you can use `$(this).is('.dropDown')` or `$(this).hasClass('.dropDown')`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new class that is common to the elements that you would like to handle the click event with:

HTML:

```
<div class="dropDown blueBG clickable"></div>
```

JS:

```
$("body").on('click', '.clickable', function(e) {
      .......
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

Attaching an event on the dynamically created elements(tags are being created through Java script) responses abruptly.
So for a definite result access the parent element of the dynamically created tags and invoke an on("Event") function.

Belowmentioned is the sample code:-----

$(".parent").on("click",".newele1,newele2",function()
{
  -----content-------------
});

For a clear picture please refer to this js fiddle example.

//jsfiddle.net/5SyS3/6/